# Cannot find symbol [Compiler error]

Tags: java, find, symbols

I've done this little program which tries to construct triangles and calculates the surface for homework and I tested it in Eclipse but when I try to upload it to our system I get 6 errors, all of the same type:

> > > /test/src/math.test/TestTriangleFunctionPublic.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
> > >       import math.NotATriangleException;
> > >                 ^
> > >       symbol:   class NotATriangleException
> > >
> > > /test/src/math.test/TestTriangleFunctionPublic.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
> > >       import math.Triangle;
> > >                 ^
> > >       symbol: class Triangle
> > >       location: package math
> > >
> > > /test/src/math.test/TestTriangleFunctionPublic.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
> > >       actual = Triangle.calculateArea(a, b, c);
> > >                              ^
> > >       symbol:   variable Triangle
> > >       location: class TestTriangleFunctionPublic
> > >
> > > /test/src/math.test/TestTriangleFunctionPublic.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
> > >       } catch (NotATriangleException e1) {
> > >                          ^
> > >       symbol:   class NotATriangleException
> > >       location: class TestTriangleFunctionPublic
> > >
> > > /test/src/math.test/TestTriangleFunctionPublic.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
> > >                   actual = Triangle.calculateArea(a, b, c);
> > >                            ^
> > >       symbol:   variable Triangle
> > >       location: class TestTriangleFunctionPublic
> > >
> > > /test/src/math.test/TestTriangleFunctionPublic.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
> > >               } catch (NotATriangleException e) {
> > >                        ^
> > >         symbol:   class NotATriangleException
> > >         location: class TestTriangleFunctionPublic

This are the two classes:

```
package math;

public class Triangle {
    static double s;
    double surface = 0;
    static double a;
    static double b;
    static double c;

    public double calculateArea(double a, double b, double c) throws NotATriangleException{
        if (a<= 0.0 || b <= 0.0 || c <= 0.0){
            throw new NotATriangleException("Cannot construct Triangle!");
        }
        else if( (a+b)<=c && (a+c)<=b && (b+c)<=a){
            throw new NotATriangleException("Cannot construct Triangle!"); 
        } 

        else {
            s = ((a + b + c)/2);
            surface = Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
            return surface;
        }

    }
    public double getErgebnis (){
        return surface;
    }
}
```

and the Exception class:

```
package math;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class NotATriangleException extends Exception {
    public NotATriangleException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
    public NotATriangleException(String message,Throwable throwable) {
        super(message, throwable);
    }
}
```

I'm disappointed because I can't figure out what's wrong!

Comment: Show us the TestTriangleFunctionPublic class.

Comment: the problem seems to be in "TestTriangleFunctionPublic.java", but code is not in post?!?

Answer (score 2):

You have a class called `TestTriangleFunctionPublic`. I think you had this class in the same `math` package in Eclipse, but when you uploaded it, you changed the location to a directory called math.test.

Comment: +1 The directory should be `math` not `math.test`  No wonder it cannot find the class.

Comment: The TestTriangleFunctionPublic class was not part of the homework. I think it's created by the programm that tests and compiles  our homework. Thanks for the fast help but I have to ask a professor what the problem was.